# How to tell if the sphinx search server is maxed out with connections

Tags: php, logging, sphinx

How is it possible to tell whether my sphinx search server is maxed out with connections? Is there any logging done by searchd automatically and is there any logging that I can do in my application to check if the error was caused by the search server being maxed out with connections or some other reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be logging the output of GetLastError when queries fail.

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-getlasterror

Also could log getLastWarning. You can call it after every query, and log it if not empty.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I am already doing that whenever the sphinx result returns false. But these fields are very often empty because the result could not be found. Is there any api call to find if the result was false because no result was found or there was some other kind of error. Presently I am assuming this to be the case if the res is returned false and the `getLastError` and `getLastWarning` functions return empty strings

Comment: $res will only be false if the query FAILED - in which case check getLastError. A query that worked, but simply has no results, will give you information about the query, and just have a empty 'matches' array. example: http://nearby.org.uk/geograph/sample2.php?q=asdfasdfasdf&pretty=1

Comment: But I am getting false in these cases too. I search for something I know is not there in the DB and the result that is sent back to me is false. Did this happen earlier and stopped happening after some api update? I can try with the new library then.

Comment: If you are getting back false, you have a failure in your system. Under normal circumstances that shouldnt happen. This has always been teh case from the very first versions of sphinx. Again you should be checking getLastError if you get false. It should at least have a clue. Check aslo your queries are reaching the query-log. Maybe something is stopping your application even contacting sphinx.

Comment: Any idea what could be the issue. I have had this since I started developing with sphinx and everything else works fine. I am using the sphinx PHP api. Could this have anything to do with it?

Comment: in itself the PHP api is fine. I've never observed your issue. And have multiple production setups using sphinx via the API. You really do need to do more logging. If getLastError is not giving you anything useful, may have to go lower level. Check socket connections are happening - look in _Connect in sphinx sphinxapi.php for example

Comment: You're right. The issue wasn't in sphinx or the PHP api. There was a small coding error, which was incorrectly returning a false where it should not have. Has been resolved. Thank you.